# How To open ports on Ubuntu in Google cloud platform

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to run an ubuntu apache server on Google cloud platform, I have created the VM instances but I can't connect to any other port apart for from 80 and 22.
Here are all the things I've tried so far:

- Created Firewall rules to allow ingress traffic to ports 21,20 and 443.[image]

  - Created FireWall rules on the Ubuntu Machine itself

[image]

The only ports that seem to be open are the 80 and 22.

[image]

I also allowed both HTTP and HTTPS access in the VM settings
[image]

So Basically, what I am trying to do is to open ports on my server. I'm not sure what am doing wrong.

Comment: When you say you want to open ports ... open ports allowed for WHICH source clients?  In your hilighted Firewall rules, you are allowing connections from machines in 10.128.0.0/9 addresses.  From WHERE do you wish to allow clients?  From the internet?  If yes, then either specify IP ranges or specify 0.0.0.0/0 to allow ALL clients from anywhere.

Comment: The rule that you circled allows internal traffic (systems with networks on the same VPC). You do not have a similar rule allowing external traffic from the Internet. The only ports that you have enabled for Internet traffic is 22, 80, 443 and 3389 + ICMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already installed apache, and it's running on the port 80 as you can see on the nmap test, a closed port just mean that there's no application running on that port, this is different to filtered, see [this](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) for more information, this confirms that your firewall rules are correct (you are allowing traffic from all sources 0.0.0.0/0). By now you should be able to access your website on the port 80, if not I suggest you to follow this [GCP guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache).

So, if you want to run apache on the port 443 you just need to change its configuration (basically you will need to get a certificate for your server, configure some related parameters and then create a virtualhost listening on the 443 port, there are many guides on the internet for this just google for "enable https apache [your_OS]"), that should be enough since the firewall rules on GCP and your instance appear to be properly configured.